# Find all path in a graph where the ends have more than 2 connections

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, graph, networkx

Given a graph, I would like to code an algorithm in python to identify all possible paths which have more than 2 connections at the ends.

For example,

[image]

This graph has the edges as follow:

```
[[0,1],[1,2],[0,3],[1,4],[2,5],[3,4],[4,5]]
```

All possible paths where the start and end node have more than 2 edges are as follow:

```
[[1,0,3,4],[1,4],[1,2,5,4]]
```

As another example,

[image]

The edges and desired paths are:

```
edges = [[1,4],[1,2],[1,5],[2,4],[2,5],[5,3],[4,3]] 
paths = [[1,4],[1,2],[1,5],[2,4],[2,5],[5,3,4]]
```

Comment: Is your question printing all paths that given the source to destination

Comment: And please provide your answer(clearly) to the second example. it is not that clear for the question you that asked

Comment: There is no source and destination, just all paths in the graph that doesn't have 3 or more edges at the ends

Comment: In the last case, what about `[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5, 3, 4], [1, 5, 2, 4], [1, 5, 3, 4]...` etc?

Answer (score 2):

You might want to use the `networkx` package (and, specifically, its `all_simple_paths` method):

```
import networkx as nx
from itertools import chain, combinations

# Build the graph
G = nx.Graph()
G.add_edges_from([[0, 1], [1, 2], [0, 3], [1, 4], [2, 5], [3, 4], [4, 5]])

# Find all paths
paths = list(chain(*(nx.all_simple_paths(G, u, v)
                     for u, v in combinations((n
                                               for n in G.nodes
                                               if G.degree[n] > 2), 2))))
```

First you need to find all the couples of nodes with degree greater than 2 with the `combinations` method. Then, you simply need to compute all the paths connecting each pair of nodes with the `all_simple_paths` method.